# AWS Lake Formation AccessDenied

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lake-formation

I've enabled Lake Formation and tried to create a Database but no matter what I still get an error:
*Insufficient Lake Formation permission(s): Required Create Database on Catalog*

I'm using root account with all privileges. I even gave **AWSLakeFormationDataAdmin** privilege explicitly without success. I've added myself (user) to Data Lake Administrator but I cannot add myself to Database Creator (AWS Lake Formation > Permissions > Admins and Database Creators):

*Resource does not exist or requester is not authorized to access requested permissions.*

So basically the only thing I'm capable of is to register S3 location.
Is there something I do wrong?

Comment: Hi, did you manage to fix it ? I have a similar problem, either with a lamba or a iam user, both with `lakeformation:*` rights.

Comment: Check out the underlying S3 bucket's resource policy. Maybe there is an explicit deny that blocks you.

I would also try doing the same action with `aws` cli, it might give more details